# Is it more common to put the street that runs north and south first when referring to an intersection?

Tags: word-usage

Consider the [intersection](https://goo.gl/maps/VwXKgbJHJdN6jvbS8) shown below

[image]

To refer the intersection, should I say

> the intersection of H St NW and 17th St NW

or

> the intersection of 17th St NW and H St NW

Even though I searched by "H St NW and **17th St NW**", Google Map put "**17th St NW**" first, is there some kind of rule?

Is it more common to put the street that runs north and south first?

Comment: This is very likely city-specific, possibly even area-within-city specific. Most often I would go with whichever is the "more important" street first, and if equal in that regard probably choose whichever I would approach the intersection by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Side note: We normally do not include the directional when identifying an intersection. That is, you would say "the insersection of 17th and H", not "17th NW and H NW".

But to answer your question: It doesn't matter which you put first. You can say "the intersection of 17th and H" or "the intersection of H and 17th". They mean the same thing.

Comment: You clearly are not familiar with street addresses in Wasington D.C., where there are two 15th streets and two K streets, and specifying which quadrant of the city you mean is critical. The example clearly involves Washington. I suggest an edit.

Comment: The question appeared to be a general question about naming intersections, not specifically about Washington DC, even though the map shown is apparently from DC. That's why I said "normally". I do not live in DC and I have not been there in many years, so if DC has a 17th NW/SW and also a 17th NE/SE, okay, then in the case of DC, you would need the directionals, and it's an exception to the general rule.